# Constructing an Equidistributed set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, ergodic-theory

I want to construct a subset $A \subset [0,1]$ of measure $0<\epsilon <1$, such that for any interval $J \subset [0,1]$ we have $m(A \cap J)=m(A)m(J)$. If anyone has any hints it would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can also get this without the LDT: Suppose there exists such a set $A.$ Because $m(A) < 1,$ there exists $U$ open in $[0,1]$ such that $A\subset U$ and $m(U) < 1.$ Now $U$ is the pairwise dijoint union of intervals $I_n, n=1,2,\dots $ So we have $A =A\cap U = \cup_n (A\cap I_n).$ Because the sets $A\cap I_n$ are pairwise disjoint,

$$m(A) = \sum_n m(A\cap I_n) = \sum_n m(A)m(I_n) = m(A)[\sum_n m(I_n)] = m(A)m(U).$$

Since $m(A)>0,$ the above implies $1 = m(U),$ contradiction.

Comment: The Lebesgue measure of every measurable set is by definition the infimum of the measures of the open sets containing it. It's easy to see that the set of rationals in $[0,1]$ is contained in open sets of arbitrarily small measure.

Comment: you are, of course, right. My bad.

Answer (score 6):

Of course $A=[0,1]$ and $A=\emptyset$ are trivial examples, or they *were* examples until you added the condition $0<m(A)<1$. With that condition added there are no examples. This follows for example from the Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem applied to $\chi_A$: If $A$ is equidistributed in the sense you specify then LDT shows that $\chi_A=m(A)$ almost everywhere, hence $m(A)=0$ or $m(A)=1$.